# Trig problem. Finding triangle height causing feedback loop.

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to design a structure that has a cross brace that needs to touch the top and bottom girter, but to do this I need to figure out how far apart to drill the holes.

The whole structure is defined by parameters, so almost any value(positive number above a minimum of 1 foot) can be entered and an answer should be possible. The relevant parameters to this question are Height(**H**), Width(**W**), and CrossBrace Diameter/2(**D**).

The values that I need to find are Verical Spacing Between Holes(**G**) and or Vertical Space Between Girter And Hole(**A**)

[Problem Visual 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxYSW.jpg)

In this visualization, we have 2 columns, one on the left and one on the right. The hole needs to be drilled in the middle(displayed by dotted line) of each column in order to receive a bolt.

[Problem Visual 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k73iQ.png)

The cross brace(angled box) in this structure needs to remain as close to the girters(top and bottom horizontal boxes) as physically possible, and it needs to be able to do this for any angle between 0deg and 90deg.

[Brace/Girter Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4HJT.png)

The smaller critical value that needs to be found in this problem is **A**.

if **A** is know than **G** is easy to calculate as

G = H-2A

The condition that this system must meet is that for any combination of input values the top corner of the cross brace needs to touch the bottom line of the top girter with no space or overlap. The same must be true for the bottom corner of the cross brace and the top line of the bottom girter.

[Failed Solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va9w2.png)
[Failed Solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OmMp.png)
[Successful Solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mNaO.png)
[Successful Solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APRav.png)

In this problem using looping functions is not allowed due to program limitations. Is there an equation that can be created to find the values **G** or **A** for any valid combination of values **H**, **W** or **D**

Edited to add more detail and clarity, please let me know if anything else needs clarification.

Comment: Please provide additional information, some of us are good a trig but have no idea what is a cross brace. Also, the meaning of G. H.W and d would be good to know.

Comment: G, W, and H are shown in the images provided. A cross brace is simply a bar that is meant to stabilize (or Brace) a shape like a square so that it doesn't become a rhombus when we don't want it to.

Comment: Where are the girders in the diagrams? Are you trying to figure out how to cut notches in the braces. It is not clear from the diagrams what you want to do.

Comment: Which of the four quantities have known values?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to first obtain an expression for $H$ given $G$, $W$, and $d$, then solve this equation for $G$.

to this end, the distance between the pivot points of the diagonal cross brace is simply $L = \sqrt{G^2 + W^2}$.  Then by similarity of triangles, we have
$$\frac{x}{d} = \frac{G}{L}, \quad \frac{y}{d} = \frac{W}{L}, \tag{1}$$ where $x$ and $y$ are the horizontal and vertical projections of $d$.  The sum $x+y$ represents the total vertical distance between a pivot point and the closest horizontal girder.  So we have $$H = 2(x+y) + G = \frac{2d(G+W)}{\sqrt{G^2 + W^2}} + G, \tag{2}$$ and we need to solve this equation for $G$ in terms of $H, W, d$.  Unfortunately, we can see this requires the solution to the quartic polynomial
$$G^4 - 2H G^3 + (H^2 + W^2 - 4d^2) G^2 - 2W(HW + 4d^2) G + (H^2 - 4d^2)W^2 = 0, \tag{3}$$ which is in general irreducible.

However, for a numeric solution given real-world values, it is not difficult to solve $(3)$ using Newton's method with the initial guess $g_0 = H - 2d$ which is, in most cases, sufficiently close to the desired real-valued root.

---

For instance, suppose that we have $H = 27$, $W = 59$, $d = 2$.  Then we expect $G$ to be a number between $H - 2\sqrt{2} d \approx 21.3431$ and $H - 2d = 23$, and we need to solve
$$f(G) = G^4 - 54G^3 + 4194G^2 - 189862G + 2481953 = 0.$$

We set up the Newton's recursion relation
$$g_{n+1} = g_n - \frac{f(g_n)}{f'(g_n)} = \frac{3 g_n^4-108 g_n^3+4194 g_n^2-2481953}{2 \left(2 g_n^3-81 g_n^2+4194 g_n-94931\right)}.$$  Then for an initial guess $g_0 = H - 2d = 23$, we obtain the iterates
$$\begin{array}{c|l}
n & g_n \\
\hline
 0 & 23. \\
 1 & 21.7216203485633537447008949600 \\
 2 & 21.8579311404132064640564339471 \\
 3 & 21.8594788931508960949005540666 \\
 4 & 21.8594790932670376032372675915 \\
 5 & 21.8594790932670409486983795515 \\
\end{array}$$

This gives, to a reasonably high precision, the desired value of $G$ in as few as five iterations.

While an elementary closed-form solution does exist for the quartic, it is very long and inconvenient to use in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a stab at it, making certain assumptions about the diagrams.

Assumption 1: $H=G + \text{ twice the width of the girder}$

Assumption 2: $W = \text{ horizontal distance between right ends of upper & lower girders}$

Assumption 3: $d=\dfrac{1}{2}\times \text{ width of brace}$

Then, if $B= \text{ length of brace}$, we have, from the Pythagorean theorem that

$$ W^2+G^2=(B-2d)^2 $$

Furthermore, if we let $\theta = \text{ horizontal angle between beam & brace}$ then we have

$$ \theta=\arctan\left(\frac{G}{W}\right) $$

This would also determine the angle of the cuts at the ends of the brace, assuming you want cuts there.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for taking a stab at it. I have spent some more time to clarify the question. unfortunately cutting the angles is not practical. As many as 100s of these braces might need to be made, and the man hour cost of cutting them is not acceptable at this time.